# Error: Oledb transaction is completed, it is no longer available;

Tags: vb.net, transactions

This question title matches with other but not the scenario,

here am getting data form a table A and based on it, updating table B and inserting a record in table C, so to make this a grouped these queries a transaction but in run time getting this error, everything seems to be correct, worked on the same scenario in c#.net and working fine but it is the first time trying to apply in vb.net getting error any help would be appreciated

the error will be in the following line

cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, CON1, transaction)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is unnecessary:

```
If CON1.State Then Con1.Close()
CON1.Open()
```

Your connection `CON1` associated with `transaction` has closed then the transaction has ended.

Comment: thank you @Ripple it is working fine now, i have remove the line.